# Mention 2 names in one comment

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-question, answers, comments

Is it possible to mention 2 names in one comment? For example, I want to write same answer for two people. I tried to do through "," and ";" but it did not work.

Comment: This is a stack exchange thing, so it should be on http://meta.stackexchange.com/. There are [some answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment) already

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No - this is by design.

If you have a reply to something a commenter has asked, respond to them. For another commenter, reply to them separately.

Remember, though, comments are supposed to be brief and temporary, and used to gain clarification of a point - plan for having them deleted.

Comment: also note that you don't need to mention the author of the post you are commenting on, they get pinged automatically anyway.